# B-field strength inside current loop antenna

Tags: rf, microwave, pcb-antenna

I want to comprehend the design of a microwave antenna designed by Sasaki et al. (arXiv:1605.04627 [cond-mat.mes-hall])[image: Microwave Antenna designed by Sasaki et al.][image: Magnetic Flux Density plotted over X-Y plane at antenna eye]

As can be seen in Fig 2a the magnitude of B is strongest in the center of the eye in the antenna. Why is that? Shouldn't the magnitude decrease quadratically with distance to the conductor? At least it does when I simulate the geometry myself. I can't reproduce the results presented in the paper. Are there high frequency (2.87 GHz) effects I am completely missing here?

Comment: Isn't your B-field model that of a wire loop rather than a copper dipole?

Comment: Are you referring to the second figure? Thats the result from the paper. The circle is the inner edge of the eye in the antenna shown in figure 1. The square is the area of the sample (shown as the grey rectangle in the cross-section in fig 1).

Comment: The question refers this report:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.04627.pdf It presents a device to excite magnetic resonances in nitrogen inside diamonds. I'm afraid it's quite far from the comfort zone of most practical electricians like me. The shown structure is quite small when compared to the free space wavelength which is about 10 cm. But it isn't a free space case, it happens in a circuit board which obviously is made of the same material than microstrip transmission lines. It's well possible that the real wavelength is so small that waves must be taken into the account.

Comment: (continued) I guess most of the magnetic field is caused by the changing electric field - as a part of the electromagnetic wave. It cannot be calculated like there was AC current around the hole edge. The structure must be taken into the account as whole.